# Find eigenvalues and eigenvectors of particular Toeplitz matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, tridiagonal-matrices, toeplitz-matrices

Assume a matrix in this form:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
b       & c        & 0            & \dots        & 0          & a     \\
a       & b        & c            & 0            & \dots      & 0     \\
0       & a        & b            & c            & \ddots     & \vdots\\
\vdots  & \ddots   & \ddots       & \ddots       & \ddots.    & 0     \\
0       & \cdots   & 0            & a            & b          & c     \\
c       & 0        & \cdots       & 0            & a          & b     \\
\end{bmatrix}_{n \times n}
$$

I want to check that the eigenvalues are of the form
$$ \lambda_p = ae^{-2\pi ip/n}+b+ce^{2\pi ip/n}$$ with associated eigenvector $$ v_p = v_{p,j} 
= e^{-2\pi ipj /n}$$ I only find information about determinant of tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix but not for this case. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried checking what happens if you multiply the vector with the matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply multiply the matrix with each eigenvector and notice that you obtain

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
b       & c        & 0            & \dots        & 0          & a     \\
a       & b        & c            & 0            & \dots      & 0     \\
0       & a        & b            & c            & \ddots     & \vdots\\
\vdots  & \ddots   & \ddots       & \ddots       & \ddots.    & 0     \\
0       & \cdots   & 0            & a            & b          & c     \\
c       & 0        & \cdots       & 0            & a          & b     \\
\end{bmatrix}
v_p = (ae^{-2\pi ip/n}+b+ce^{2\pi ip/n})v_p = \lambda_p v_p
$$

directly from the matrix definition. It would be significantly harder to actually find $v_p$ and $\lambda_p$ without knowing them beforehand, but since you are given $n$ candidate solutions (with $1 \leq p \leq n$), one only needs to check that they indeed form eigenpairs.

Comment: I thought there was proof or something, but you're right about knowing them beforehand!

Answer (score 1):

In the case you don't know beforehand the eigenvectors, you can refer to the fact that your matrix is [**circulant**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix). The eigenvectors of a $n \times n$ circulant matrix are the columns of the Discrete Fourier matrix $F_n$ (this is also explained in the referenced Wikipedia article) and it is precisely those which are given to you...

Comment: Why downvoting this answer ? Doesn't it bring a **discovering** methodology for the eigenvectors, therefore for the eigenvalues ?